# Easy Transfer from a dead computer

Tags: windows-7, easy-transfer

I had a computer that electrocuted me and the company sent me a new one.  The hard drive from the old computer works fine and is in my new computer.  I would like to transfer my files from the old drive to the new one, preferably using Easy Transfer (old & new computers were Win7).

When I go through the Easy Transfer wizard, it assumes my old computer is running and that I can run a process to backup all my data to a single file.  However, in my case I have the system drive in my new computer and want to pull the data off it.

I would like to avoid rebooting the old computer, to avoid damage to myself or my data.  I would like to avoid booting into the old system drive, as my new hardware is significantly different and I imagine I'll run into some missing hardware issues.

What's the easiest way to get my data off this drive?

Edit:
Since there's no way to make Easy Transfer work without resurrecting the dead computer, I'll just manually copy all the app settings & documents from each profile.

Comment: If I'm reading this right, you have the old drive as a 2nd physical drive in the new box, yes? If so, I can't imagine anything easier than copy and paste if we are just talking about docs, photos, muisc, vids etc.

Comment: It almost seems as if the old drive is installed in the new machine.  Is this not the case?  "The hard drive from the old computer works fine and is in my new computer"

Comment: yes, copy and paste works, and is fast.  I was just looking for a way to just click once to get all my documents & program data.  Now I have to go through each profile and do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are even the least bit handy with computer hardware you can remove the disk from the old computer and plug it into the new.  Then you simply copy the files you want from the old disk.

There are many online guides to building desktop computers.  Any of these will show you how to unplug and plug in a hard disk.  If the new computer is a laptop you may need an external USB disk enclosure.

Edit or comment with hardware details and somebody here at SU will probably post additional help.

Comment: both desktop machines.  i've already put the old drive in my new computer, and i'm just copying the files by hand.  i was hoping to just say "grab all my profiles and app settings" but that's life.  at least it's a fast transfer.

Answer (score 0):

You can either copy/paste it or use something like `robocopy`.

`robocopy "src" "dst" /S` or `/MIR` (`mir` will delete things from `dst` if it isn't in `src`) and other commands will make things nicer.

But you could copy paste unless you can't. Here is a command reference https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html